# Find combination of continuous ranges returning max sum

Tags: python, c#, sql-server, math, statistics

I have an SQL Table resembling the following

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE YourTableName (
    val FLOAT,
    p300 FLOAT,
    p100 FLOAT
);
-- Insert values into the table
INSERT INTO YourTableName (val, p300, p100)
VALUES
    (2295.91836734693400, -1.370, -2.340),
    (1538.77551020407994, -0.035, 0.135),
    (1269.68503937007615, -0.041, 0.300),
    (-1130.38277511960990, -0.160, -0.075),
    (1004.27350427350345, -0.070, 0.030),
    (-2396.37305699481525, -0.210, 0.580),
    (1632.46268656716000, -0.090, 0.290)
```

I need to find the combination of continuous ranges for columns p100 and p300 that return the max possible result in column val. This example is for 3 columns, but my real world case has more columns and more rows.

I firstly did a script finding the max sum subarray for each property seperately. This worked. Then I proceeded to try finding the max sum submatrix between p100 and p300, but I realized that this wouldn't work, as each of these has to be continuous and I can only order the matrix in one way.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C# and python?

Comment: I've seen alot of these kind of problems coded in C++, C#, Python and Java. C# and Python are part of the stack I've used trying to solve it.
Example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-submatrix/?ref=gcse

Comment: Please show your desired results.

Comment: And you need to be specific about technology you want to solve the problem with i.e. SQL, python etc. But choose one only

Comment: So if you have used C# and Python to solve it - what is the question then? If you need to solve it with SQL  - please remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: What's a continuous range

Comment: In the end I need either indices or direct floor and ceiling values for p100 and p300. Example of each of p100 and p300 max range and lastly how they are combined.
https://ninjagostorage.blob.core.windows.net/pub/ex.png

Comment: Please add all relevant information directly to the question, as formatted text - not images

Comment: I didn't manage to solve the problem. This is the stack I'm using while trying to solve the problem.

The final result should give bottom and sealing values for p100 and p300, that when filtered by, produce the max possible sum in the val column.

Finding out what the values in the 4 filters below are, is the problem that I'm after.

SELECT * FROM WHERE  
p300 >= -0.09 AND p300 <=-0.07
AND p100 >=0.03 AND p100 <= 0.29

Comment: You can order them. I don't really have to use sql. I thought that it is good to do an example with sql, because everybody can run the script and have the data in a second. Currently the data is in SQL, but then I pull the data with C# and go on to do manipulations in code. I also tried python as it has alot of libraries aimed at stuff like this. Still no working solution though.

Comment: Yeah, now that i think about it, sounds pretty tricky :D

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have a potential solution, but it seems too neat, so I probably missed something :P

```sql
CREATE TABLE YourTableName (
    val FLOAT,
    p300 FLOAT,
    p100 FLOAT,
    ix int IDENTITY
);
-- Insert values into the table
INSERT INTO YourTableName (val, p300, p100)
VALUES
    (2295.91836734693400, -1.370, -2.340),
    (1538.77551020407994, -0.035, 0.135),
    (1269.68503937007615, -0.041, 0.300),
    (-1130.38277511960990, -0.160, -0.075),
    (1004.27350427350345, -0.070, 0.030),
    (-2396.37305699481525, -0.210, 0.580),
    (1632.46268656716000, -0.090, 0.290)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    , row_number() OVER(ORDER BY p300) AS sort
    FROM    YourTableName
    )
, cte2 AS (
    SELECT  val AS sum, c.sort, c.ix, CAST(ix AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS path
    FROM    cte  c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.val + c2.sum, c.sort, c2.ix, CONCAT(path, '_', c.ix)
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN cte2 c2
        ON  c.sort = c2.sort + 1
     )
SELECT TOP 1 x.ix, x.path, max(sum)
FROM (
    SELECT c.*
    ,   y.p100
    ,   CASE WHEN lag(p100) OVER(partition BY c.path ORDER BY p100) <> ISNULL(y.prev100, -9999999999) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS unordered
    FROM    cte2 c
    CROSS apply STRING_SPLIT(c.path, '_') x
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT p100
        ,   lag(p100) OVER(ORDER BY p100) AS prev100
        ,   ix
        FROM    YourTableName y
        ) y
        ON  y.ix = x.Value
    ) x
GROUP BY x.ix, x.path
HAVING max(unordered) = 0
ORDER BY MAX(sum) DESC

--5445.198
--DROP TABLE YourTableName
```

First, I added an identity column to quickly identify a row in the matrix.

Then I created a recursive [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) which loops every row sorted by the p300 value.

Every iteration creates a "path" which is basically a way to trace how rows were combined into a sum. For example, 1_2_3_5 meaning rows in the path were 1, 2, 3, 5.

The loop will then sum rows 1 - 6, 1 - 5, 1 - 4, 1 - 3, 1 - 2, 1 - 1, 2 - 6... etc.

Finally, I unwrap the path by doing a string_split, and fetch the original row from the matrix. The matrix inside the join is fixed so it also fetches the previous p100 value. This value is compared to the previous value of the generated path table. This is to make sure we actually respect the sequence of the values and not jump around.

Finally, I group by the sum and path where there aren't any "unordered" rows.
Then it's easy to fetch the maximum sum.

This code should be easy to adapt for another p-value. Just add another *LAG* and make sure to check for continuous values.