# How to upload a file in a nested directory to Storage accounts File Share service using Python SDK?

Tags: python, django, directory-structure, azure-file-share

I am trying to upload a file to the path, using ShareDirectoryClient Class of Azure Python SDK.I have attached below the code and errors that I am getting.

```
path = "users/user11/projects/assets/fbx"
directories = path.lower().strip("/").split("/")
for directory in directories:
    try:    
        directory_client = directory_client.get_subdirectory_client(directory)
        if not directory_client.exists():
            directory_client.create_directory()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)

with directory_client.get_file_client(file_name=upload_file.name) as file_client:
    file_client.upload_file(data = file_content, length=len(file_content))
    print("Uploaded")
```

The "directory_client" is an object of ShareDirectoryClient, which is used in the above code snippet to create directories. The problem faced is, with every directory that is being created I get the below Exception.

```
('The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.\nRequestId:fc43b173-e01a-000c-1ae8-bd388a000000\nTime:2023-07-24T04:37:52.5072468Z\nErrorCode:InvalidResourceName',)
```

ClientAuthenticationError

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. 

ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed authenticationerrordetail:The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'E0eObuCq+OdHAtf4qG80kb3wprxR4vwIsDpjinnVvUM=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT.......'
```

And sometimes I even get ClientAuthenticationError. I'm not really sure, what is creating the problem in both the cases.

Any solutions and suggestions are open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I faced here is, I am trying to create directories inside File Share directly, but instead there should some directory present before trying to create a new directory.
So, I manually added a `root` folder inside the File Share, that fixed my problem.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

To upload a file to a nested directory in an Azure Storage File Share using the Python SDK (Azure Storage File Share SDK), you'll need to follow these steps:

1. Install the required libraries:
   Make sure you have the `azure-storage-file-share` package installed. If not, you can install it using pip:

```bash
pip install azure-storage-file-share
```

2. Authenticate with your Azure account:
   You need to create an Azure Storage account and get the connection string or account key to authenticate your Python script.
3. Write the Python code to upload the file:
   Use the Azure Storage File Share SDK to interact with your Storage account and upload the file.

Here's an example code that shows how to upload a file to a nested directory in an Azure Storage File Share:

```py
read more [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://%20https://www.espioninfotech.com/blog/the-future-of-influencer-marketing-trends-and-best-practices
```

Comment: Kindly, provide useful information, or reference links. The steps are all followed and the error which I get is while creating a directory and uploading it.

Comment: What this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)? [The previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719916/find-combination-of-continuous-ranges-returning-max-sum/76719987#76719987) seems to have been.

Comment: Related: *[Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)*

Comment: The last line raises suspicion of link spam. Or is it a hallucinated URL?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).